# Saved data to device's local storage is cleared after closing app in production

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I created `React-native` app for tourism purpose using `Expo`. So app checks if device have an internet connection. If so, app downloading all data from cloud and save it to device local storage. If not, then app using old data saved previously to local storage, when device had an internet connection.

The problem is, that when app is closing, local storage is cleared automatically, but it shouldn't. The problem exist only in production and on both `iOS` and `Android` devices. Both devices have enough space in memory.

How to prevent device's local storage from clearing automatically?

To handle local storage I'm using `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` package.

### UPDATE:

`app.js`file. The only place where data is downloaded and added to local storage.

```
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import * as Network from 'expo-network'
import { collection, getDocs, query, where } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { db, storage } from './firebase'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
import Languages from './screens/language'
import Home from './screens/home'
import { getDownloadURL, ref } from 'firebase/storage'
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system'
import AllObjectsCategories from './screens/allObjectsCategories'
import ObjectCategory from './screens/objectCategory'
import Object from './screens/object'
import ObjectMap from './screens/objectMap'
import AllRoutes from './screens/allRoutes'
import Route from './screens/route'
import RouteObjects from './screens/routeObjects'
import RouteMap from './screens/routeMap'
import { changeFilename } from './globalFunctions/changeFilename'

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

export default function App() {
  const [loadedData, setLoadedData] = useState(false)
  const [selectedLanguage, setSelectedLanguage] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()
      const notworkStatus = await Network.getNetworkStateAsync()

      const deleteOldFiles = new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        if (notworkStatus) {
          await FileSystem.deleteAsync(
            FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'images',
            {
              idempotent: true
            }
          )
          resolve()
        } else {
          resolve()
        }
      })

      Promise.all([deleteOldFiles])
        .then(async () => {
          const getAllObjects = new Promise((resolve) => {
            if (notworkStatus) {
              getDocs(
                query(
                  collection(db, 'lankytini_objektai'),
                  where('data.published', '==', true)
                )
              )
                .then(async (snap) => {
                  let array = []
                  let filesList = []

                  snap.forEach((element) => {
                    let data = JSON.stringify(element.data())
                    data = JSON.parse(data)

                    array = [...array, data.data]

                    const files = {
                      id: data.data._id,
                      files: [data.data.main_image, ...data.data.gallery_images]
                    }

                    filesList = [...filesList, files]
                  })

                  try {
                    const snapString = JSON.stringify(array)
                    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@tourist_objects', snapString)
                    resolve(filesList)
                  } catch (error) {
                    console.warn(error)
                    resolve(filesList)
                  }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.warn(error)
                  resolve([])
                })
            } else {
              resolve([])
            }
          })

          const getAllRoutes = new Promise((resolve) => {
            if (notworkStatus) {
              getDocs(
                query(
                  collection(db, 'marsrutai'),
                  where('data.published', '==', true)
                )
              )
                .then(async (snap) => {
                  let array = []
                  let filesList = []

                  snap.forEach((element) => {
                    let data = JSON.stringify(element.data())
                    data = JSON.parse(data)

                    array = [...array, data.data]

                    const files = {
                      id: data.data._id,
                      files: [data.data.main_image, ...data.data.gallery_images]
                    }

                    filesList = [...filesList, files]
                  })

                  try {
                    const snapString = JSON.stringify(array)
                    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@routes', snapString)
                    resolve(filesList)
                  } catch (error) {
                    console.warn(error)
                    resolve(filesList)
                  }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.warn(error)
                  resolve([])
                })
            } else {
              resolve([])
            }
          })

          await Promise.all([getAllObjects, getAllRoutes])
            .then(async (results) => {
              const touristObjectsFiles = results[0]
              const routesFiles = results[1]

              const downloadTouristObjectsImages = new Promise(
                async (resolve) => {
                  if (touristObjectsFiles.length > 0) {
                    const promises = touristObjectsFiles.map(
                      (touristObject) => {
                        return new Promise((resolve) => {
                          const filesPromises = touristObject.files.map(
                            (file) => {
                              return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
                                if (file !== '') {
                                  await getDownloadURL(
                                    ref(
                                      storage,
                                      `/images/objects/${touristObject.id}/${file}`
                                    )
                                  )
                                    .then(async (url) => {
                                      const fileReference = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}images/objects/${touristObject.id}`

                                      await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(
                                        fileReference,
                                        {
                                          intermediates: true
                                        }
                                      )

                                      await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
                                        url,
                                        `${fileReference}/${changeFilename(
                                          file
                                        )}`,
                                        {
                                          sessionTyle:
                                            FileSystem.FileSystemSessionType
                                              .BACKGROUND
                                        }
                                      )
                                        .then((uri) => {
                                          resolve()
                                        })
                                        .catch((error) => {
                                          console.warn(error)
                                          resolve()
                                        })
                                    })
                                    .catch((error) => {
                                      console.warn(error)
                                      resolve()
                                    })
                                } else {
                                  resolve()
                                }
                              })
                            }
                          )

                          Promise.all(filesPromises)
                            .then(() => resolve())
                            .catch((error) => {
                              console.warn(error)
                              resolve()
                            })
                        })
                      }
                    )

                    Promise.all(promises)
                      .then(() => resolve())
                      .catch((error) => {
                        console.warn(error)
                        resolve()
                      })
                  } else {
                    resolve()
                  }
                }
              )

              const downloadRoutesImages = new Promise(async (resolve) => {
                if (routesFiles.length > 0) {
                  const promises = routesFiles.map((touristObject) => {
                    return new Promise((resolve) => {
                      const filesPromises = touristObject.files.map((file) => {
                        return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
                          if (file !== '') {
                            await getDownloadURL(
                              ref(
                                storage,
                                `/images/routes/${touristObject.id}/${file}`
                              )
                            )
                              .then(async (url) => {
                                const fileReference = `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}images/routes/${touristObject.id}`

                                await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(
                                  fileReference,
                                  { intermediates: true }
                                )

                                await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
                                  url,
                                  `${fileReference}/${changeFilename(file)}`,
                                  {
                                    sessionTyle:
                                      FileSystem.FileSystemSessionType
                                        .BACKGROUND
                                  }
                                )
                                  .then(() => {
                                    resolve()
                                  })
                                  .catch((error) => {
                                    console.warn(error)
                                    resolve()
                                  })
                              })
                              .catch((error) => {
                                console.warn(error)
                                resolve()
                              })
                          } else {
                            resolve()
                          }
                        })
                      })

                      Promise.all(filesPromises)
                        .then(() => resolve())
                        .catch((error) => {
                          console.warn(error)
                          resolve()
                        })
                    })
                  })

                  Promise.all(promises)
                    .then(() => resolve())
                    .catch((error) => {
                      console.warn(error)
                      resolve()
                    })
                } else {
                  resolve()
                }
              })

              Promise.all([downloadTouristObjectsImages, downloadRoutesImages])
                .then(async () => {
                  try {
                    const language = await AsyncStorage.getItem(
                      '@selected_language'
                    )
                    setSelectedLanguage(language)
                    setLoadedData(true)
                  } catch (error) {
                    console.warn(error)
                    setLoadedData(true)
                  }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.warn(error)
                  setLoadedData(true)
                })
            })
            .catch((error) => console.warn(error))
        })
        .catch((error) => console.warn(error))
    }

    getData()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const hideSplash = async () => {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync()
    }
    if (loadedData) {
      hideSplash()
    }
  }, [loadedData])

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

Comment: data doesn't get automatically cleared from async storage. unless code is present to delete it . 

could  you please provide the details of the code so that I can check?

Comment: I updated my question with code, but for me it looks good and it works (in dev mode). Maybe I have add some additionally parameters to `app.json` file?